# POST coding characters

Tags: android, character-encoding, http-post

I am sending a POST message to a php server with two parameters, one is a HASH in Base64. Base64 use the character "=" as padding so it can appear in the value of the hash.

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "WAFFTE="));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "data"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

with this code the url is encoding the "=" by %3D, but in that case the server does not reconize the id value. I have tried selectinf different coding but no difference.

```
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs),"UTF-8");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not necessary to remove "=" from post arguments but it is recommended to avoid confusion with separators. So the best is to use the flags URL_SAFE and NO_PADDING in the Base64 encoding.

I hope this can help other with the same problems.